# xmllint problems to output lines

Tags: xml, bash, xml-parsing, sitemap, xmllint

I know that my question includes 2 questions...

At first, I want to use xmllint to output "loc" content tags. The sitemap I load has got a xmlns="...".

On xmllint shell, I need to do this:

```
setrootns
xpath //defaultns:loc
```

That works... no problem. But I need to do this in a bash script.

(AFAIK) xmllint hasn't got option to tell "let's go, setrootns" so I cannot do this:

```
xmllint --xpath "//loc" sitemaps.xml
# or
xmllint --xpath "//defaultns:loc" sitemaps.xml
```

This is the first question, how can I tell to xmllint to load the default ns ?

If I can't, let's take a look on my second solution:

I can remove xmlns attribute and then, there os no ns to use:

```
xmllint --xpath "//loc" <(sed -r 's/xmlns=".*?"//' sitemaps.xml)
```

But... now... the whole response of my 500 "loc" content is concatenated in one line !...

I tried this too:

```
xmllint --shell sitemaps.xml <<EOF
setrootns
xpath //defaultns:loc/text()
EOF
```

Or again

```
xmllint --shell sitemaps.xml <<EOF
setrootns
cat //defaultns:loc
EOF
```

The first gives me (for example)

```
465  TEXT
    content=http://...
```

with truncated url

The second gives me "------" every 2 lines... and a "/>" at last line...

And I begin to be very nervous... :)

A big thanks if you find any solution.

The goal is to have every location, one per line.

Comment: What about using a better XML shell? See [xsh](http://p3rl.org/XML::XSH2).

Comment: My [Xidel](http://videlibri.sourceforge.net/xidel.html) always uses the namespaces prefixes of the input file for unknown prefixes and the default namespace in the query

Comment: @choroba the goal was to use xmllint ;) but yes, I guess I will use another tool...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I used to do something similar:

```
clean_xml_message=$(echo "$xml_message" | sed 's/xmlns/ignore/')
```

Eventually you could try to put back the new lines:

```
sed 's/></>\n</g'
```

I guess you only want the URL without the `<loc></loc>` ?
Then I would select all the loc elements with xmllint:

```
<loc>...</loc><loc>...</loc><loc>...</loc>
```

Then add the new lines: `sed 's/<loc>/<loc>\n/g' | sed 's#</loc>#\n</loc>#g'`

```
<loc>
...
</loc><loc>
...
</loc><loc>
...
</loc>
```

Finally remove the tags `grep -v "<loc>" |grep -v "</loc>"` or a single `grep -v "$<"` could do it. (-v is the invert selection: http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?grep)

Comment: this is exaclty as 

   grep -Eio "<loc>(.*?)</loc>" sitemaps.xml | sed -r 's/<.?loc>//g

But the goal was to use xmllint options :)

Comment: I didn't understood what you meant, and I realize this is a nice solution you give. I try this, thanks

Comment: Thanks a lot, check my answer, I've found how to not check namespace, and I append \n after <loc> tags.

Answer (score 6):

@BrnVrn is right, I only had to append "\n" after  tags

Then I found my answer about namespaces, I can use local-name to not check default namespace

So, I did this:

```
xmllint  --xpath "//*[local-name()='loc']/text()" <(sed 's/<loc>/<loc>\n/g' sitemaps.xml)
```

And it works !

Thanks to all

Answer (score 0):

For the newline problem you can have a look at this repo:

https://gitlab.gnome.org/cykerway/libxml2

And its merge request:

https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/libxml2/merge_requests/8

Basically it gives you a choice of separator in a xpath nodeset result. So with this `example.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<menu>
    <food>
        <name>Hot Chocolate</name>
        <price>$1.99</price>
    </food>
    <food>
        <name>Iced Tea</name>
        <price>$2.99</price>
    </food>
</menu>
```

You can do:

```
# xmllint --xpath "//name/text()" --xpath-separator "\n" example.xml
```

Output:

```
Hot Chocolate
Iced Tea
```